# How delete cascade with mysql

Tags: mysql

I have 2 tables.

```
CREATE TABLE `imovel` (
  `id_imovel` int(11) NOT NULL,
  `titulo` varchar(255) NOT NULL,
  `tipo` varchar(100) NOT NULL,
  `categoria` varchar(100) NOT NULL,
  `dormitorios` int(11) NOT NULL,
  `banheiros` int(11) NOT NULL,
  `suites` int(11) NOT NULL,
  `vaga_garagem` int(11) NOT NULL,
  `endereco` varchar(255) NOT NULL,
  `bairro` varchar(255) NOT NULL,
  `valor` double NOT NULL,
  `area_total` double NOT NULL,
  `descricao` text NOT NULL
) ENGINE=InnoDB DEFAULT CHARSET=latin1;

CREATE TABLE `imagens` (
  `id_imagem` int(11) NOT NULL,
  `caminho` varchar(255) NOT NULL,
  `tipo` varchar(50) NOT NULL,
  `imovel_id` int(11) NOT NULL

) ENGINE=InnoDB DEFAULT CHARSET=latin1;
```

So I have relationships between them from 1 to n.

How do I delete the "imovel" with all the relationships he has.

Thank you for your help

what is the right way to do this?

Comment: Enforce foreign key relationship with `ON DELETE CASCADE` behavior.

Comment: That will require `PRIMARY KEY`s by the way.